# How to call methods inside of a Backbone Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone.js, well even new to Javascript, not sure how to put my question in phrase, I want a function to be called and returns result as an attribute in the same collection.

```
var EnrollmentCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    url: "/some/prefix" + this.getPath() + "/some/suffix",

    getPath: function() {
        var result;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/this/is/a/url',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                result = data[0].someattribute;
            }
        });

        return result;
    }
});
```

As you can see, getPath() method should be returning a value as value of url, however, browser gives following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPath' of undefined(anonymous function)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to fetch a url asynchronously? Or is the url defined in the ajax function the one you want to use, ie. '/this/is/a/url'

Answer (score 2):

With the code you are using:

```
url: this.getPath(),
```

You are executing the function `this.getPath()` and it doesn't exist yet because it is defined below.

Try doing

```
url: (function(){
  var result;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/this/is/a/url',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                result = data[0].someattribute;
            }
        });

        return result;
}())
```

Comment: getPath is a method on an object, it won't be available for 'url' even if it is defined above

Comment: @som you are right, i was wrong. I updated my answer to something that will work.

Comment: the above will return 'undefined' for the url, as result is only defined after the ajax call has completed

Comment: @som i don't agree you on that. The ajax call is set to "async: false" and that will the process to wait until it is done, so result will contain the message in success.

Comment: Thanks for the your help. Now I'm wondering if url is consisted of several strings, each string comes from a different function. Then I'll have to call each function one by one and combine them together in the end. In this case, is @Kenzo-kun's answer below the only way?

Comment: if you don't wrap the function (ie. `url` is simply a method), you should be able to call any additional functions from within, referring to `this` as you would in any other method on the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Add `initialize` method for your collection, and add `_.bindAll(this)` like this:

```
initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this);        
}
```

After adding the code above, you can now call your method like this:

```
url: this.getPath();
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @MindTastic's answer above, and with the revelation of `async: false` (to create a blocking ajax call), i would consider simply moving your `getPath` method onto `url`:

```
var EnrollmentCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    // doesn't need to be wrapped as 'url' accepts functions
    url: function () {
        var result;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/this/is/a/url',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                result = data[0].someattribute;
            }
        });

        return result;
    }
});
```

See the [Backbone Docs - Collection URLs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url) for more info